# Rest API populating multiple people picker - populates my user AND "SPO Crawler"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Ok so this is a weird one. I'm trying to populate a multiple people field like this ->

`UsersToNotify = { "results": [10,50,563]};`

Lets say 10 is my id. After i create the item through rest (create, not update) i can see my name in the field, HOWEVER, the other 2 guys are not added, but something is...I can see my name and `_spocrawler_64_9123`

What is that and why is it taking the "place" of the other 2 people?

Found the issue: The id's were wrong. I have 2 separate forms in my app, one to a site collection and another to a different site collection. I had to break that down in 2 people pickers since one was ensuring the user on site collection A and the other needed to ensure on site collection B.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are putting the users in as SharePoint expects.  You are missing some delimiters.  SharePoint is looking for `user_id;#user_name;` in an array to populate multiple users.  Try using something like the for you variable:

```
var usr=arryuser.get_id()+";#"+arryuser.get_loginName()+";";
finalusers.push(usr);
```

Comment: So it should look like this ? ``6;#username;`` and the actual call to be ``{ "results": ['6;#username;', '11;#username2;'] };`` to the SP field ``UsersToNotifyId`` ? 

Unless i understood that wrong, it doesnt work, its expecting INT32. 

Regardless of the way i create my array, could you perhaps just show me how the call for the field should look like ? ex: ``"UsersToNotify":  {"results":......`` with 2 users ? It would be easier for me to figure it out. (I'm using reactJS so code other than the REST call are rather useless to me.
Thanks!

Comment: Found my issue, apparently my approach was correct, but had the wrong id's (by mistake the ensure call was made to another site since i've got 2 calls in the same app). I'm still curious about your approach here if you could elaborate on it.